# Add min-max to control system block

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to add min-max limits to the control system blocks in [Example: Control system principles](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/control-system-principles/)? Could pin edge do this?

[image: PID control block with max and min limits]

Comment: It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make this work with `pin`s.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,decorations}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{strange pin}{initial}
{
\state{initial}[width=0pt,next state=final] {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-2pt}}}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-12pt}}}
  }
}

\begin{document}


\tikzset{block/.style={draw, fill=blue!20, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em},
sum/.style={draw, fill=blue!20, circle, node distance=1cm},
input/.style={coordinate},
output/.style={coordinate},
custom pin/.style={pin edge={solid,semithick,black,decorate,decoration={strange pin}}}}

% The block diagram code is probably more verbose than necessary
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=Latex]
    % We start by placing the blocks
    \node [input, name=input] {};
    \node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
    \node [block, right of=sum] (controller) {Controller};
    \node [block, right of=controller, pin={[custom pin]above:Disturbances},
            node distance=3cm] (system) {System};
    % We draw an edge between the controller and system block to 
    % calculate the coordinate u. We need it to place the measurement block. 
    \draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=u] {$u$} (system);
    \node [output, right of=system] (output) {};
    \node [block, below of=u, pin={[custom pin]below:duck}] (measurements) {Measurements};

    % Once the nodes are placed, connecting them is easy. 
    \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$r$} (sum);
    \draw [->] (sum) -- node {$e$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$y$}(output);
    \draw [->] (y) |- (measurements);
    \draw [->] (measurements) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} 
        node [near end] {$y_m$} (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]